# Setting launch iamge for iphone4

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, iphone-5, iphone-4

I have set launch image to my app. I have used asset catalog. I am using xcode 5. In that I have drag and drop two images to iphone portrait ios7. When I run application in iphone 5 simulator it is showing me launch image but when i test it to iphone 4 simulator it is not displaying. I searched in asset catalog for that but i didnt find anything

[image]

In screen shot you can see it is showing me for only two images

Comment: Can you write down your launch images names?

Comment: I have given launch,launch@2x

Comment: for iphone 5 it is working fine but problem is for only iphone 4

Comment: File name is irrelevant when using asset catalog. Do you have a yellow warning? Make sure you have 640x960 for 2x and 640x1136 for R4

Comment: Based on your screen shot, you are not using asset catalog. Click on that button where it says "Use asset catalog".

Comment: @Desdenova...sorry I have upload wrong image But I upload only to show you that where to set for iphone 4...It is only showing me to set for 5

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not using asset catalog. Click the `Use Asset Catalog` button and import images for Launch Image.
2. In edit image screen, show image `Attributes Inspector` tab in `Utilities Panel`, uncheck all checkboxes in `iOS 7.0 and Later` section and check related checkboxes in `iOS 6.0 and Prior` section, then try again.

You might feel a bit strange, but just have a try. I encounter the same problem last month when using Xcode 5.0.1.